# How to trigger a Graphic's click event when it gets added to map?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using Esri Javascript API 4.5

When the map loads, I'm fetching point coordinates from external source and then plotting it on the map using `Graphic` class and assigning a `PopupTemplate` to that graphic.

## The Case

The graphic is successfully plotted on the map. But in order to view to the popup template, I'm required to click on the graphic.

## The Issue

Is there way where I can trigger the graphic's click event when it gets added to the map so that the popup template shows up automatically?

## The Code

```
require([    
"esri/PopupTemplate",     
"esri/Graphic",
.
.
.
.
"dojo/domReady!"
],
function (
    PopupTemplate, Graphic, ....) {

var point = {
    type: "point",
    x: <some x>,
    y: <some y>
 };    

var symbol = {
   type: "picture-marker",
   url: "/euf/assets/nl/images/red-pin.png",
   width: "30px",
   height: "30px"
};

var template = new PopupTemplate({
    title: "New Title",
    content: "New Content"
});

var graphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: point,
    symbol: symbol,
    popupTemplate: template
});
view.graphics.add(graphic); // this works as I can see the marker on page

// now, how do I trigger its click event here?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the view's default [Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html) object. Set the `location` property using the point graphic's geometry.

```
....
view.graphics.add(graphic);

var popup = view.popup;
popup.title = 'My Popup';                    
popup.content = 'My Popup Content';
popup.location = graphic.geometry;      
popup.open();
```